# Swift 2 - UIAlertView printing in debug console

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I just upgraded to xCode 7.0 (beta) and now I have output in the console each time a `UIAlertView` is shown. Here is the output :

> 2015-06-27 16:23:39.184 xxxxxx[2415:66289] kbd-alignment-view finished(YES) moving from {{0, 667}, {375, 0}} to {{0, 667}, {375, 0}}

Is there a way to get rid of it ?

Here is an exemple of how I show the `UIAlertView`. The outputs were not present before Swift 2.0.

```
    func userDidUpdate()
    {
        let title = "xxxx"
        let message = "xxxx"

        UIAlertView(title: title, message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
    }
```

Comment: Can you use `UIAlertController` instead?

Comment: @ndmeiri `UIAlertView` uses `UIAlertController` internally. Mos likely, the log output will be present as well.

Comment: @LeoNatan Oh really? I wasn't aware of that. Does it say so in the docs somewhere?

Comment: @ndmeiri No, it's internal implementation detail. You can inspect the view hierarchy to see for your self, or see [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIAlertView.h), there is a member called alert controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine. Remember that the iOS 9 SDK is still in very early beta. This log is internal Apple debug information which they have not yet removed. If you feel strongly about this, open a bug report with Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought that it was not coming from me but was not sure. I will open a bug report at this URL.